# Calculating field from shp currently sected in ArcMap session using Python script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I need to create a script in Python for use in ArcMap 10.

This script must be able to calculate a field from the shp currently selected in ArcMap.

Any ideas? I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 2):

After running a tool in ArcMap you can go to the results window (Geoprocessing > Results) and right click on the finished tool.  This will give the option to copy the Python code that you can then paste into your Python shell of choice.  This is a great way to begin learning.  After working with Python for a couple years now I still find myself doing this just to find out how the GP tool wants the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something from your question, you're just asking how to calculate [field2] from [field1] in the same shapefile.

If so, you just need to use the "Calculate Field" tool to do this.  And if you just want to run this tool on a selected feature(s), all ArcGIS tools will only work on the selection set if one exists.

[ArcGIS Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000) has python code examples that show exactly how to do it in Python.

Look in the "Code Sample" section about halfway down help.  Their [generalized] example is:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/data"
arcpy.AddField_management("<in_table>", "<field>", "TEXT", "", "", "20")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("<in_table>", "<field_to_calc>",
                                <field_with_values>, "PYTHON")
```

If that is all you are after, it's pretty simple.